# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in known plain text attack

Tags: python, typeerror

1. I am writing a code in python to print a string as output but i get the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "xopa.py", line 413, in
>   
>       Main()   File "xopa.py", line 410, in Main
>       XOR(args[0], args[1], options)   File "xopa.py", line 364, in XOPA
>       print('Key (hex): 0x%s' % binascii.b2a_hex(result.key)) TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

2. i had removed `ord()` function because I thought its deprecated
3. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DidierStevens/DidierStevensSuite/master/xor-kpa.py

The line which error shows is below

```
print('Key (hex): 0x%s' % binascii.b2a_hex(result.key))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StacOverflow. Please update your question to include the code you're having trouble with and format it as such in th editor, remove links or pictures of such code.

Comment: Where'd you get the idea that `ord` was deprecated? It's just the opposite of `chr`.

Comment: Please mention your code and your approach which could help us to answer.

Comment: I had given link above in point 3

Comment: Python xor-kpa.py p.text nm.text

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex) the input for `binascii.b2a_hex(result.key)` is a byte object, not a string.

You can try this instead :
`print('Key (hex): 0x%s' % binascii.b2a_hex(b(result.key)))`

or

`print('Key (hex): 0x%s' % binascii.b2a_hex((result.key).encode()))`

Comment: Will this give me a string instead of byte? I also got error in ord() function for code above... Link for code is above...

Comment: You can try it and look it up by yourself :) . what type of error are you getting, can you share the log? As ord() takes a string of length ONE only. It would be more helpful if you share your console log instead of us giving your code a run.